# Problem with selenium webdriver on linux with ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver

I reinstalled ruby 2.3.1p112, and my spec test do not work.
The error was:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: add additional details to your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choice to solve this problem:

1. You can uninstall chrome-stable and install latest version of [chrome beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/) (this only because the chrome 74 for linux is not released yet)
2. You can downgrade your chromedriver version

```
bundle exec chromedriver-update 73.0.3683.68
```